# How to expand all the grouping of table by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I am trying to use material ui table with group by feature, As i was looking into the code, grouping can be expanded or shrinked using click event, however, i want to keep all expanded by default as soon as page component loads.

Below is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kbcee?file=/demo.js)

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
```